# Cannot build production the MERN stack web

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy, mern, dev-to-production

In my local it working well , but when I deploy. It can not get the endpoint of server

Here is my server code.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const SocketServer = require("./socketServer");
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require("peer");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Socket
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  SocketServer(socket);
});

// Create peer server
ExpressPeerServer(http, { path: "/" });

// Routes
app.use("/api", require("./routes/authRouter"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/userRouter"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/postRouter"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/commentRouter"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/notifyRouter"));
app.use("/api", require("./routes/messageRouter"));

const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(
  URI,
  {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected to mongodb");
  }
);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port", port);
});
```

Here is my frontend package.js

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "peerjs": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-share": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also create a middler wave proxy

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/api/**",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

And my final .env.dev file

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

Update more about fetchData in frontend

```
import axios from "axios";

export const getDataAPI = async (url, token) => {
  const res = await axios.get(`/api/${url}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const postDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.post(`/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const putDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.put(`/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const patchDataAPI = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await axios.patch(`/api/${url}`, post, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};

export const deleteDataAPI = async (url, token) => {
  const res = await axios.delete(`/api/${url}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  return res;
};
```

The idea that when i deploy production. I will changed the url in my .env file to url of frontend. But it not working cause error because can not reach the endpoint. Please help me

Comment: Can you include the error also?

Comment: this is my error when I deploy production : 
polling-xhr.js:202          GET https://chat-client-4djyhumkrq-as.a.run.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OPuQuIn 404

Comment: I also update my code fetchData